# Strapi CMS deployment external database supabase, managing content with Nuxt and images on Cloudinary

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, content-management-system, strapi, supabase

one thing is beyond me XD
how can I host strapi, e.g. on Netlify, I know that I need to have a database on the server somewhere, e.g. subapase, but it doesn't load anyway, I posted it on github, I deployed it on Netlify but it doesn't even read, does anyone know?

or some other way to manage content in nuxt, I know there is Cloudinary for photos, but how can you manage content?

I know there is pinia, and /store folder in nuxt but i completly dont know how to handle with it

I've probably read half the internet and a lot of videos on YT